# Angularjs 2 Overlay error RC 7

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I'm having some trouble with my code using the angular2-modal. Here is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Modal } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import { Overlay } from 'angular2-modal';
import { AdditionCalculateWindow, AdditionCalculateWindowData } from './custom-modal-sample';
import { DialogRef } from 'angular2-modal/models/dialog-ref'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
            <h2>Custom Modal example:</h2>
            <button (click)="openCustom()">Custom Modal</button>
  ` 
})
export class AppComponent {

 constructor(public overlay:Overlay, public modal:Modal, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.overlay.defaultViewContainer = viewContainerRef;
 }

 openCustom() {
    this.modal.open(AdditionCalculateWindow, new AdditionCalculateWindowData(2, 3));
 }
}
```

Here is my main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I got this from: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/blob/master/QUICKTHROUGH.md

When i ran my app the consoles says "Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?, Modal, ViewContainerRef)". 
It can't see the overlay and my app does not work. i wonder if there is a fix for this.

Comment: Have you imported `Overlay`?

Comment: share your full component or main module code here. it looks like you do not have imported `ModalModule.forRoot()` and `BootstrapModalModule` in main module or forgot to import `Overlay`. if possible  check after updating to angular latest 2.0.0 release as `angular2-modal` uses latest angular 2.0.0.

Comment: I'm using the latest angular 2 and angular2-modal ok i will share my full comp and main. @ranakrunal9

Comment: @ranakrunal9 edited

Comment: i guess your `app.module` is same as `QUICKTHROUGH.md` , correct ?

Comment: please check https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/issues/169

Comment: @ranakrunal9 sorry, it did not solved anything :/